# TypeScript adding node to exsisting XML

Tags: javascript, json, angular, xml, typescript

I have a XML that structure looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
   <kid>
   </kid>
</parent>
```

I wanna simply add few nodes inside parent node that it will become something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
   <kid>
   </kid>
    <data>
        <data_kid_1>{ JSON OBJECT }</data_kid_1>
        <data_kid_2>false</data_kid_2>
    </data>
</parent>
```

I have tried to use XmlJs.xml2js() convert my XML to JavaScript and then add it in that way:

```
        let jScriptXml['parent']['data'] = {
            'data_kid_1': { JSON OBJECT } ,
            'data_kid_2': false
        };
```

followed by converting it back to XML using XmlJs.js2xml() but conversion do not convert signs like & or < to entity references and that cause errors in my app

Anyone have an idea how to add that nodes without breaking XML?

Comment: In your original, you had `<kid_1>
   </kid_1>`; In your output, you have `<kid>
   </kid>`? Can you make sure these are the correct input and output?

Comment: I have changed that It should be ```<kid> </kid>```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most beautiful code in the world, but it does deliver, I think:

```
kids = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
   <kid>
   </kid>
</parent>`

xpath = require('xpath')
 , dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser; 
XMLSerializer = require('xmldom').XMLSerializer;
serializer = new XMLSerializer();
family = new dom().parseFromString(kids);

destination = xpath.select('//kid', family, true);
data = family.createElement("data");
data.appendChild(family.createTextNode("\r\n\t    "));//I added a few new lines, etc., just for presentation, but they're not strictly necessary
kid1 = family.createElement("data_kid_1");
kid1.appendChild(family.createTextNode("{ JSON OBJECT }"));
kid2 = family.createElement("data_kid_2");
kid2.appendChild(family.createTextNode("false"));
data.appendChild(kid1);
data.appendChild(family.createTextNode("\r\n\t    "));
data.appendChild(kid2);
data.appendChild(family.createTextNode("\r\n\t"));

destination.parentNode.insertBefore(data, destination.nextSibling);//drop .nextSibling to actually insert before
destination.parentNode.insertBefore(family.createTextNode("\r\n\t"), destination.nextSibling);
console.info(serializer.serializeToString(family))
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
   <kid>
   </kid>
    <data>
        <data_kid_1>{ JSON OBJECT }</data_kid_1>
        <data_kid_2>false</data_kid_2>
    </data>
</parent>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have problem with xpath when I try to run it  I getting ```Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'xpath'``` Do you have any advice?

Comment: @ArthurV Yes, that means you need to install the module: `npm install xpath`

Comment: So I need to import:
```import * as xpath from 'xpath-ts';```
                                                                          
```import { DOMParserImpl as dom } from 'xmldom-ts';```

Comment: @ArthurV I'm not sure why you'd have to do that; but can't to try. But the combination of "install" and "require" should work.